# Understanding ASP.NET MVC anti-forgery protection

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, security

In basic MVC project where all my forms have `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` I witness that the token (cookie) value is always the same for *all* forms for specific user session. Why is that? I partially understand that (otherwise there will be a lot of problems for example with Back button). But why not make it different for different forms using "salt":

> "This method is deprecated. Use the AntiForgeryToken() method instead.
>   To specify custom data to be embedded within the token, use the static
>   AntiForgeryConfig.AdditionalDataProvider property."

And why is it so huge (207 bytes in my example, user identity name is 7 chars)? Standard session id is much shorter (41).

Comment: Isn't the `AntiForgeryToken` a hidden form value?

Comment: It is. But the generated token is stored in both a cookie and a hidden field. On post their values must be the same for the validation to pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it only needs to be unique to a user session is due to how the exploit works that targets CSRF vulnerabilities;

Essentially, CSRF relies on form values being set ahead of time by a malicious user. The malicious user can only set form values, typically as GET parameters; they can not get/read values that might exist on a legitimate form, and they can not guess a 207-length code for any user, reliably.

An exception would be if there was an XSS vulnerability, where the malicious user could somehow obtain this 'live' information. But with XSS vulnerabilities present, there is little need to use CSRF, anyway.

So, as long as each user session has its own unique value, it's effectively impossible for a malicious user to craft an appropriate form submission ahead of time.

Comment: Why is that `AntiForgeryToken()' overload with salt existed anyway then?

Comment: @UserControl I suppose just to enable you to add unique functionality, if you wanted to. I can't off the top of my head imagine a type of web app that would need it, but I suppose they just wanted to allow for that possibility. Or perhaps also just to increase the randomness of the token.

Comment: Got it! Any guess on the size? Why not just hash over session id?

Comment: I'm not sure on the size; perhaps just to make it as difficult to guess as practical. Seems like something comparable to the Session ID size would work, but... As for basing it on the Session ID, my best *guess* there is that doing so would serve to make it (marginally) more predictable. Though that still seems weak, to me! so I can really only guess: to make it more difficult to guess!